# window.oneventlistener('click'): How to retain default function for clicked links?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, three.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to create [a simulation](https://riteshsingh.github.io/galaxies/) of positions of 4673 of the nearest galaxies.

I am custom handling click events to allow viewers to center on, and color galaxies to aid in study and navigation.

However, I am also linking to external information about the galaxy on clicking as well as pointing.

Now these links have lost their default function due to:

```
window.oneventlistener('click')
```

What would be the best way to restore their default behavior?

Complete code, if needed, is available [here](https://github.com/RiteshSingh/galaxies/blob/master/index.htm).

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: event.preventDefault() prevents default behavior.  remove that call to allow default click behavior

Comment: @user120242 Thank you so much!! Could you please add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.preventDefault()` prevents default behavior. Remove that call to allow default click behavior.

Comment: Dear Sir/Madam, Fortunately, this project culminated in a publication: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3668727 and https://academic.oup.com/astrogeo/article/61/4/4.42/5873800. I have tried to acknowledge your most kind help in the acknowledgements section of the paper: "**user120242 on stackoverflow.com**". Please do tell me if you would like me to modify it. I wanted to ask your name before writing it but I thought it would be a breach of privacy.

Comment: @RiteshSingh Cool! I'm glad I was able to contribute to your publication.  If you'd like my real name I don't mind providing it, but I'm fine with it the way it is.

Comment: I do feel that thanking you by name would be a better record in the long term, however, if you prefer the current format, that is perfectly ok with me :)